# typeahead-template-url causes page to ask for credentials

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have this Anuglar.js UI-Boostrap issue. I am trying to set up a custom pop up template using ui-bootstrap. however whenever the page loads then I get a pop up asking for me to type in my credentials again. their are no errors on the page and nothing fails to load across the network. If I try to login it says its not correct and if I cancel it logs me out of my application.

I slowly started to comment out different parts of code that I had added and found that when I commented out the ui-bootstrap property it no longer asked for credentials below is the following code with the ui-boostrap commented out.

```
<input type="text"  @*typeahead-popup-template-url="customPopupTemplate"*@ typeahead-min-length="0" typeahead-show-hint="false" uib-typeahead="d as d.name for d in bds | filter:{name:$viewValue,isDeleted:false}" typeahead-on-select="getStuffs($item)" ng-model="item.bd" ng-required="true" />
```

the customPopupTemplate is below which came from angulars site here (scroll down to typeahead)

http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

I originally did what the site had verbatim but still got the pop up so I put the additional markup in a partial and I load the partial on the page and I still get the same Issue. I am trying to get a custom popup to display but cant get past the website asking for credentials. I am a bit lost here and not sure where to go. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<div class="col-md-12" id="customPopupTemplate">
    <div class="custom-popup-wrapper"
         ng-style="{top: position().top+'px', left: position().left+'px'}"
         style="display: block;"
         ng-show="isOpen() && !moveInProgress"
         aria-hidden="{{!isOpen()}}"

         >
        <p class="message">select location from drop down.</p>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="listbox">
            <li class="uib-typeahead-match" ng-repeat="match in matches track by $index" ng-class="{active: isActive($index) }"
                image-checkbox ng-style="{'background-color':bgCol}" ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" ng-click="selectMatch($index)" role="option" id="{{::match.id}}">
                <div uib-typeahead-match index="$index" match="match" query="query" ng-style="{background-color:match.color" template-url="templateUrl"></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: where is your `customPopupTemplate` file located on the server? Does this work on your local device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being prompted for credentials like this when a page loads is typically caused by the web server configuration. My guess is that you're using IIS and Windows Authentication is enabled on the website, it wants your local Windows User credentials.

Try disabling Windows Authentication and Enabling Anonymous in IIS to see if you get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using ASP.Net mvc, you may need to add a web.config file where your `customPopupTemplate` is stored. First, I would recommend renaming to

`customPopupTemplate.cshtml`. Then you need to add a web.config file in the area of the project where these template files are located. Something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*.cshtml" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
    <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The key is this section within `system.webServer`. It basically allows `.cshtml` files to be served by the application:

```
<handlers>
          <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
          <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*.cshtml" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
</handlers>
```